# check whether date exists in database

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to check if the entered date is taken or not.

I tried to fix it but it always indicates that a date has been taken even if it hasn't.

This is the DAO

```
public static String getDate(String date) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Connection cnx;
    String datee;
    cnx = Connect.getConnection();

    String req = "select date from examen where date=?";
    PreparedStatement st = cnx.prepareStatement(req);
    st.setString(1, date);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        String laDate = rs.getString(date);

    }
    return date;

}
```

and this is the servlet

```
String dd = ExamDAO.getDate(date);

if (dd != null) {
                        String datePrise = "la date est prise ";
                        request.getSession().setAttribute("datePrise", datePrise);
                        System.out.println("priiiiise ");
                        response.sendRedirect("examen.jsp");
                    } else {...}
```

Comment: What type is date in your database? Date or String? One problem with dates can be different formatting like 2019-05-26 or 26.05.2019. Or possibly there is a time unequal 00:00:00 at the date. That can make finding a date difficult.

Comment: You always return the entered date, whatever happens in your method

Comment: which line @JBNizet

Comment: `return date;`: that returns the date passed as argument to the method, whether or not the if block was executed.

Comment: @JBNizet oh yeah, I've already initialized a variable called datee but didn't pay attention that I put date as return ..

Comment: @JBNizet now it works but when I enter a taken date gives error for exmple if I enter "2019-05-25" it gives java.sql.SQLException: Column '2019-05-25' not found.

Answer (score 2):

You always return the same date as passed into the method. `laDate` isn't used so your method doesn't have any working logic in it.

Could be something like:

```
\\ I suggest a better query with another name for the 'date' column (needs db change), because using column 
\\ names like date can cause problems (reserved keywords/functions in some databases)
"select registrationdate from examen where registrationdate = ?"
```

```
String returnDate = inputDate; // inputDate = date argument from method with better name
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
   returnDate = rs.getString("registrationdate");
}
return returnDate;
```

or

```
Optional<String> returnValue = Optional.empty();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
   returnValue = Optional.of(rs.getString("registrationdate"));
}
return returnValue;
```

Comment: No I can't because I don't know the expected behaviour of the method. It's for me unclear what should be returned if there is no record found that match the criteria. Should then the "input date" be returned or is null expected (then it's better to return an optional).

Comment: thanks, I resolved that and it works but when I enter a taken date gives error for exmple if I enter "2019-05-25" it gives java.sql.SQLException: Column '2019-05-25' not found

Comment: Yes, my fault. The rs.getString tries to get a column value and the inputDate is not a column name. I changed the example. It's also advisable to use better names. Names like 'date' in a database can be special keywords (depending on database).

Comment: it's just about " " rs.getString(date); should have been between guillemet

Comment: how now to let the system  remember the data entrerd by user after the redirect

Answer (score 0):

I guess, your method is to be rewritten like below if `examen.jsp` path is for dates already taken. Notice the extra declaration - `String laDate =null;` & change in `return` statement.

Also, notice change in `laDate = rs.getString("date");` , your need to extract by column name & not variable. Table column name is "date" while `date` is a variable carrying date values & not table column name.

Variable `String datee;` from your code is unused, you can remove that.

```
public static String getDate(String date) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Connection cnx;
    String laDate =null;
    String datee;
    cnx = Connect.getConnection();
    String req = "select date from examen where date=?";
    PreparedStatement st = cnx.prepareStatement(req);
    st.setString(1, date);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
         laDate = rs.getString("date");

    }
    return laDate ;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I resolved that and it works but when I enter a taken date gives error for exmple if I enter "2019-05-25" it gives java.sql.SQLException: Column '2019-05-25' not found

Comment: In my code, notice line `laDate = rs.getString("date");` double quotes around date to make it a column name & not column value.

Comment: thank u. now I want the system to remember the data entrerd by user after the redirect can u help ?

Comment: That is done by session. You are already setting one attribute in session, set as many as you like.

Comment: yes I've already set session but I don't know how to use it in this case "of saving inputs"